# Can I put this javascript on a url on my own site?

Tags: javascript, tracking

I have a tool I am using that has embedded javascript to do tracking for it's hosted landing page.

I'd like to host the landing page on my own domain, and was hoping I could take the javascript and somehow manipulate it so that it would still track but from my page and I could not worry about the hosted page management.

Here is the code...any advice on if this is possible would be great!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
johnie = '225032'; 
ehe = '2846'; 

(function() { 
function async_load(){ 
var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; 
s.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://steve' :     'http://cdn') + ‘.steveo.com/pd.js'; 
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];    c.parentNode.insertBefore(s, c); 
} 
if(window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent('onload', async_load); } 
else { window.addEventListener('load', async_load, false); } 
})();
</script>
```

Comment: We don't have any way of knowing.  We don't know anything about your tool.  Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Well, I'm a newbie so I don't know a whole bunch either :). If you mean by tool the system that does the tracking - well when I cut and paste this javascript onto a page on my site and render the page it does not work - by 'work' I mean it does not record the the page was rendered.

Comment: Tracking isn't done entirely in the client. The Javascript makes calls to the tracking server, and you'll need to replicate that on your server.

Comment: Barmar, that's above my skill level but I put this code on a page on my site and it does not track. When I look at that code I see https in the code that references the original service, to me that makes me think that this code needs to render on that domain...and so I think this is not an easy thing to do.

Comment: are `https://steve.steveo.com/` and `http://cdn.steveo.com/` valid hosts? that have a http server and a file called pd.js in the document root?

Comment: @JaromandaX They are, but those are on the service. I want to host this page myself. Does that make sense? Are you suggesting that if on my site I put the pd.js file and update those urls this may work?

Comment: I doubt that's enough

Comment: @JaromandaX ...so do I :(